# Can OR be "undone"?

Tags: logic

Suppose that $Z = X \vee Y$, where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are 96-bit binary numbers.  If I'm given the values of $Z$ and $Y$, is it possible to work out what $X$ is?

I know this is possible with XOR but can it be done with OR?

Comment: For each 0 bit in Z you know that corresponding bit in X and Y have to be 0. For each 1 bit in Z, X and Y can be any of (1,1) (0,1) (1,0). Now if Y bit is 0 then you can infer X bit as 1 BUT if the Y bit  1 then X bit can be 1 or 0 and there is no way to figure out which one it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to find out that there can be more than one value, used as $X$, to satisfy $Z = X \vee Y$. When a specific bit of $Y$ is $1$, there are two possibilities for such bit in $X$, i.e., $0$ or $1$.

Let's make a simple example with a 2-bit number:

$Y$ = $10$ and $Z$ = $11$

The possible values of $X$ are:

- $11$
- $01$

because:

- $11 \vee 10 = 11$
- $01 \vee 10 = 11$

In short, you don't have the certainty that the end result of the reverse operation of $\vee$ will be a unique result.

Comment: X, Y, Z are 96 bits binary numbers. 
EX:
Z = 001100010001010000100101011110111111010101110100010110000101011000101010000011100001111000000000

Comment: It does not matter how many is the number of bits of $Z$. You can save 96-bit numbers in two 64-bit integers: long long in C++, and Long in Java, or you can preserve it in a string data type. Then, let us assume that $Z = 1111$ and $Y = 1111$. $X$ could be from $0000$ to $1111$; therefore there is no a single value for $X$ to obtain.

Comment: @beginner1010's point is that the problem is the same whether you are talking about 1 bit or 96 bits, as the bits in two 96 bit number are treated independently by $\lor$.

Comment: @Dave Clarke if I have
**Z =**
01111100110110101001011111111101111111111111101101101101011110111011110100000011‌​1110011010101110 

**Y=** 01101100010100101001010111101001110101011101000101100001010110001010100000000011‌​1100000000001010 

Is it possible to get **X** value which is equal to : 01011000100010100001001010111101111110101011101000101100001010110001010100000000‌​0110011010100100

From Z and Y ??

Comment: @SHdotCom: First, think about whether you can do this for a 1-bit number.  It's the same problem for a 96-bit number, just 96 times.

Comment: So, sometimes you can be 100% sure, but only in the following scenario:  Z = 1 and Y = 0 -> X = 1. Generally on such large numbers, you only narrow down the possible options. But it's still better than 2^96.

Comment: Dave Clarke, with 1-bit you have only two possibilities to get **X** 0 or 1 , but with 96bits How many Combinations of (1 and 0) you can make to get one value equal to X??

Comment: @SHdotCom: The number of possibilities is equal to $2^{Y_1}$, where $Y_1$ is the number of ones in binary number $Y$.